# Is there a layout switcher in EE2?

Tags: matrix, forms, grid, ifelse

Ok so I have this dreamweaver extension called tab panel menu where each menu I can generate either a single column, 2 column, 3 column, 4 column, 5 column or sub menu. Now I wish to make use of this inside EE2 without having to do it on dreamweaver. I figured to make use of if:else statement for the html output. My problem if I want to generate column within channel entries? So if Field 1 = Layout Selection, Field 2-7 = Show field for Selected layout(Of course in horizontal order with labels' like For right sidebar, for left sidebar, for middle content).

So that if I were to write a new channel entry, I can just select layout and then fields for that layout will show up.

Example:
  -On Channel Entry-
  Field 1 - Layout Selection
  (col-default
  col-75-25
  col-60-40
  col-50-50
  col-40-60
  col-33-33-33
  col-25-75
  col-25-50-25
  col-25-25-25-25
  col-20-20-20-20-20)
  Field 2 - Content A
  Field 3 - Content B
  Field 4 - Content C
  Field 5 - Content D
  Field 6 - Content E
  Field 7 - Content F

-On template-
  Some channel code here
  {if layout_selection == "col-20-20-20-20-20"}
  <div class="p7mgm-row mgm-col-20-20-20-20-20 col-sep">
  <div class="p7mgm-Col p7mgm-percent20">
  <div class="p7mgm-ColContent p7ehc-51">
  {content_a}
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="p7mgm-Col p7mgm-percent20">
  <div class="p7mgm-ColContent p7ehc-51 border-left">
  {content_b}
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="p7mgm-Col p7mgm-percent20">
  <div class="p7mgm-ColContent p7ehc-51 border-left">
  {content_c}
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="p7mgm-Col p7mgm-percent20">
  <div class="p7mgm-ColContent p7ehc-51 border-left">
  {content_d}
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="p7mgm-Col p7mgm-percent20">
  <div class="p7mgm-ColContent p7ehc-51 border-left">
  {content_e}
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

{if:elseif layout_selection == "col-25-25-25-25"}
  <div class="p7mgm-row mgm-col-25-25-25-25 col-sep">
  <div class="p7mgm-Col p7mgm-percent25">
  <div class="p7mgm-ColContent p7ehc-50">
  {content_a}
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="p7mgm-Col p7mgm-percent25">
  <div class="p7mgm-ColContent p7ehc-50 border-left">
  {content_b}
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="p7mgm-Col p7mgm-percent25">
  <div class="p7mgm-ColContent p7ehc-50 border-left">
  {content_c}
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="p7mgm-Col p7mgm-percent25">
  <div class="p7mgm-ColContent p7ehc-50 border-left">
  {content_d}
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

{if:elseif layout_selection == "col-25-50-25"}
  <div class="p7mgm-row mgm-col-25-50-25 col-sep">
  <div class="p7mgm-Col p7mgm-percent25">
  <div class="p7mgm-ColContent p7ehc-49">
  {content_a}
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="p7mgm-Col p7mgm-percent50">
  <div class="p7mgm-ColContent p7ehc-49 border-left">
  {content_b}
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="p7mgm-Col p7mgm-percent25">
  <div class="p7mgm-ColContent p7ehc-49 border-left">
  {content_c}
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

{if:elseif layout_selection == "col-25-75"}
  <div class="p7mgm-row mgm-col-25-75 col-sep">
  <div class="p7mgm-Col p7mgm-percent25">
  <div class="p7mgm-ColContent p7ehc-44">
  {content_a}
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="p7mgm-Col p7mgm-percent75">
  <div class="p7mgm-ColContent p7ehc-44 border-left">
  {content_b}
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

{if:elseif layout_selection == "col-33-33-33"}
  <div class="p7mgm-row mgm-col-33-33-33 col-sep">
  <div class="p7mgm-Col p7mgm-percent33">
  <div class="p7mgm-ColContent p7ehc-48">
  {content_a}
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="p7mgm-Col p7mgm-percent33">
  <div class="p7mgm-ColContent p7ehc-48 border-left">
  {content_b}
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="p7mgm-Col p7mgm-percent33">
  <div class="p7mgm-ColContent p7ehc-48 border-left">
  {content_c}
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

{if:elseif layout_selection == "col-40-60"}
  <div class="p7mgm-row mgm-col-40-60 col-sep">
  <div class="p7mgm-Col p7mgm-percent40">
  <div class="p7mgm-ColContent p7ehc-46">
  {content_a}
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="p7mgm-Col p7mgm-percent60">
  <div class="p7mgm-ColContent p7ehc-46 border-left">
  {content_b}
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

{if:elseif layout_selection == "col-50-50"}
  <div class="p7mgm-row mgm-col-50-50 col-sep">
  <div class="p7mgm-Col p7mgm-percent50">
  <div class="p7mgm-ColContent p7ehc-43">
  {content_a}
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="p7mgm-Col p7mgm-percent50">
  <div class="p7mgm-ColContent p7ehc-43 border-left">
  {content_b}
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

{if:elseif layout_selection == "col-60-40"}
  <div class="p7mgm-row mgm-col-60-40 col-sep">
  <div class="p7mgm-Col p7mgm-percent60">
  <div class="p7mgm-ColContent p7ehc-47">
  {content_a}
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="p7mgm-Col p7mgm-percent40">
  <div class="p7mgm-ColContent p7ehc-47 border-left">
  {content_b}
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

{if:elseif layout_selection == "col-75-25"}
  <div class="p7mgm-row mgm-col-75-25 col-sep">
  <div class="p7mgm-Col p7mgm-percent75">
  <div class="p7mgm-ColContent p7ehc-45">
  {content_a}
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="p7mgm-Col p7mgm-percent25">
  <div class="p7mgm-ColContent p7ehc-45 border-left">
  {content_b}
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

{if:elseif layout_selection == "col-default"}
  <div class="p7mgm-row mgm-col-default">
  <div class="p7mgm-ColContent">
  {content_a}
  </div>
  </div>

{if:else}
  What the?! where is my Content!!!
  {/if}

Some channel code here

Comment: I'm sorry, but I couldn't understand what you want to do. You can write the HTML whatever way you want to. You can have a Field to the user choose the layout and change all the HTML or just change a class to use different CSS.

Comment: I just updated my Q

Comment: Wow! This is really complex for the user! But, OK... Why can't you use a field named `layout_selection`?

Comment: This is actually for my own site. Just starting out.

Comment: I did do that, I know this can be done using a multi-select or radio button but it gets confusing so that why i'm looking for an entry addon that SHOWS i'm on the current selected layout and hides other fields with template tags so I can use this procedure for other content generating html/css3 codes other than tab panel menu. Each Field/{Content} = Grid and within Grid I can create a video/image gallery, footer links, or an audio player widget when possible. :)

Comment: IMHO while you can do this sort of thing with EE, I'm not sure I see the value in it. EE works best when you determine the content types in a website, and build channels and templates to suit each content type.

It feels like you want to sort of recreate Dreamweaver or use EE as a "page editor" and that's not really how it's best used...;)

Answer (score 2):

If I understood what you want, maybe one of these add-ons can help you:

- [Entry Type](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/entry-type) - A dropdown fieldtype that shows/hides other fields on the publish page;
- [Better Pages](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/better-pages) - Better Pages is an ExpressionEngine fieldtype designed to make using the Pages module significantly more end-user friendly;
- [Entry Layout](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/entry-layout) - Lets you link custom fields to any entry of your website. It will let you save a different publish layout for two different entries even if they come from the same channel. Useful for static pages such as contact, about pages, etc... Plus, its support member groups;
- [Plates](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/plates) - This fieldtype for ExpressionEngine 2 is a drop in replacement for the native Pages Module or Structure Module ‘Template’ field;

Answer (score 0):

You might find [Template Snippet Select](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/template-snippet-select) useful if you want to allow a way of choosing a layout template in the publishing form. Works well with snippets or full templates :)